# Do a SUM in the same row PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a sum in php. Sorry for the possibly simple question, I'm a PHP beginner. I cannot figure out if is a PHP or MySql problem.

I have written some PHP with a MySql table with 2 fields called 'January' and 'February'. The people put a number in January and February and I can see both values in the database.

Example of January:

```
echo "<input name='january' value='".Html::formatNumber($this->fields["january"], true)."'>";
```

But, I have another form with Total and i'll try to save it in Mysql too.

I've written this:

```
$total = ($this->fields["january"]+$this->fields["february"]);
$this->fields["total"] = $total;
Html::autocompletionTextField($this, 'total', array('value' => $total, 'size' => 60));
```

At the bottom i've a "Save" Button and the result is:
If i'll write 15 on January and 14 on February i can see in the form the right result, 29. 
But in Mysql i'll see again 0.

If i push again the "Save" button, i can see the right resul also in Mysql, 29.
I must push twice save becasue the software, with the first "Save" put the value in January and/or February, and seems to sum the "old" values. If i push again "Save", Mysql see the last value and sum it rightly.

The MySql Syntax for the values are:
 [January](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Uwx9.png)
 [Total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGDsb.png)

EDIT: January and February are in the same row, in each rows.

Comment: So the problem is actually in the MySQL / database part - and for that reason, you decided to _not_ show us any of that? Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry CBroe, is my first post. I can edit with Mysql Syntax now of value

Comment: You should limit your post to the essential part, I don't see anything PHP related to your problem.

Comment: To improve your answer, you can strip out all the echoes which do nothing functional. That way our focus goes to the relevant parts :)

Comment: To the downvoters, please help OP how to improve his answer, especially as this is the first question

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you may do:

```
SELECT (a+b) as s from mytable;
```

Even so your question is not clear at all, this might be the perfect answer.